# Replacing string comparison with pattern

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a bot developed with the Bot Framework (https://dev.botframework.com/) and this bot is supposed to to specific things based on the incoming command.

In my code I therefore have a method that contains multiple (9 to be exact) if-statements. (See the example below). that parses the incoming command. I'm trying to find a good pattern to make the code nicer. Maybe 9 if-statements is ok but I see a potential risk that these statements can increase in the future. I've been looking at the strategy-pattern but don't really see it to be a good candidate. What pattern could be a good replacement for multiple if-statements?

```
if (text.Contains("command1")) {
   doA();
}

if (text.Contains("command2")) {
   doB();
}

... an so on.
```

Comment: Would the string `"aaabbb"` be processed by both `doA` and `doB` in your example?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: The language is C# and the strings "aaa" and "bbb" are only examples. I've updated the question with better values.

Comment: Store Command objects in a map, where keys are strings. When you receive text, get the Command object from the map, and execute it.

Comment: Can `text` contain multiple commands? If so, should they all be executed?

Comment: At the moment the answer to your question Vitali is no. For now only one command is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a strategy pattern for this. A simple example below:

Declarations:

```
class ResponseStrategy
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IInputHandler> _responses;

    public ResponseStrategy(IEnumerable<IInputHandler> responses)
    {
        // TODO protect from null input, etc.
        _responses = responses;
    }

    public ?void? Respond(string input)
    {
        // TODO put error handling in place and expect input to match no handlers
        _responses
            .First(r => r.CanHandle(input))
            .Handle(input);
    }
}

interface IInputHandler
{
    bool CanHandle(string input);
    ?void? Handle(string input);
}

class DoAInputHandler : IInputHandler
{
    public bool CanHandle(string input)
    {
        return input.contains("command1");
    }

    public ?void? Handle(string input)
    {
        // DoA();
    }
}

class DoBInputHandler : IInputHandler
{
    public bool CanHandle(string input)
    {
        return input.contains("command2");
    }

    public ?void? Handle(string input)
    {
        // DoB();
    }
}
```

Setup:

```
var responses = new List<IInputHandler>
{
    new DoAInputHandler(),
    new DoBInputHandler(),
    // other handlers
};
var responseStrategy = new ResponseStrategy(responses);
```

Usage:

```
responseStrategy.Respond("asl;daskjnfsd command1 asdsdgdfn");
```